# How to open a message in a modal pop-out when a user successfully/unsuccessfully registers

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, razor

The code below is the submit button for registering a new user

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                <form method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" id="" value="Register" class="buttonRegister btn btn-default" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 25px"/>
                </form>
            </div>
```

This is the Controller for Registering a new user to the database. When a user successfully registers they need to see the ViewBag.ErrorMessage in a modal popout partial view using javascript

I Thought returning the partial view containing the ViewBage.ErrorMessage would be the best idea.

```
 public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    // GET: Register
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Indexes the specified model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PatientScreeningAssignment.Models.Register model)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = null;
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Oops something went wrong...";
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_PartialMessage.cshtml");

        try
        {
            //Add new staff to the database
            Patient_Screening_Library.Database_Methods.Register.RegisterNewStaff(model.EmailAddress.ToUpper(), model.Password.ToUpper().Trim(),
                model.FisrtName.ToUpper(), model.SurName.ToUpper(),
                model.JobTitle.ToUpper(),
                model.PhoneNumber, model.PagerNumber, model.DateOfBirth
                );

            //Return Message success
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = null;
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Successfully registered user!";
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_PartialMessage.cshtml");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = null;
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_PartialMessage.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

This is in the _PartialMessage View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
</body>
```

I want this to be a popout Modal Form when i click n the submit button which is located in the Register View

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In your partial.

```
<head>

</head>
<body onload="popupMyMsg('@ViewBag.ErrorMessage')">

</body>
<script>
 function popupMyMsg(msg)
 {
    alert(msg);
 }
</script>
```

Or Redirect in your Register with this

```
 <body onload="popupMyMsg('@ViewBag.ErrorMessage')">

 </body>
 <script>
     function popupMyMsg(msg)
     {
        if(msg != null && msg!="")
           alert(msg);
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: Should i put the script in the shared layout and the html in the partial view? or in my Register View with the submit button?

Comment: If you redirect in your partial put this in your partial. Else you can redirect in your Register but change the function.